# Recieving high volume data in client browser using Jquery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, bulk

I am in the process of making a WordPress based application where a student can take the examination on his web-browser. The questions will be randomly selected and served from the question bank stored in a WordPress CMS.

In this regard following is important to share:

-each examination can have as many as 100 multiple choice questions.

-Each question can have images, each choice can have associated images.

-since the examination is time bound I can not send request to server every time the student completes his question.

My query is :

How do I send the questions from the server:

-should I send the whole question set in one go and then have the Java Script parse all the questions and choices parsed at the client side

or

-should the client repeatedly request the questions from server in the background in the chunks of say 5 question each, for example. If this is better approach I am not sure how do I implement this. Any pointers?, please.

Or is there a third approach which I am not aware of.

Please advise for any comments and solutions for the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: depends on user's selection,send appropriate JSON data to client and render it dynamivally.

Comment: or is it a better option - to compose a .xml file at the wordpress and send it across to client(student) , where it will be parsed by jquery/javascript. What could be the issues - disadvantages in this approach ?

Answer (score 1):

**Depends on user's selection,send appropriate JSON data to client and render it dynamivally,but if you want to use XML then lets talk about it:**

I should mention that this comparison is really from the perspective of using them in a browser with JavaScript. It's not the way either data format has to be used, and there are plenty of good parsers which will change the details to make what I'm saying not quite valid.

**JSON is both more compact and (in my view) more readable - in transmission it can be "faster" simply because less data is transferred.**

In parsing, it depends on your parser. A parser turning the code (be it JSON or XML) into a data structure (like a map) may benefit from the strict nature of XML (XML Schemas disambiguate the data structure nicely) - however in JSON the type of an item (String/Number/Nested JSON Object) can be inferred syntactically, e.g:

```
myJSON = {"age" : 12,
          "name" : "Danielle"}
```

The parser doesn't need to be intelligent enough to realise that 12 represents a number, (and Danielle is a string like any other). So in javascript we can do:

```
anObject = JSON.parse(myJSON);
anObject.age === 12 // True
anObject.name == "Danielle" // True
anObject.age === "12" // False
```

In XML we'd have to do something like the following:

```
<person>
    <age>12</age>
    <name>Danielle</name>
</person>
```

(as an aside, this illustrates the point that XML is rather more verbose; a concern for data transmission). To use this data, we'd run it through a parser, then we'd have to call something like:

```
myObject = parseThatXMLPlease();
thePeople = myObject.getChildren("person");
thePerson = thePeople[0];
thePerson.getChildren("name")[0].value() == "Danielle" // True
thePerson.getChildren("age")[0].value() == "12" // True
```

Actually, a good parser might well type the age for you (on the other hand, you might well not want it to). What's going on when we access this data is - instead of doing an attribute lookup like in the JSON example above - we're doing a map lookup on the key name. It might be more intuitive to form the XML like this:

```
<person name="Danielle" age="12" />
```

But we'd still have to do map lookups to access our data:

```
myObject = parseThatXMLPlease();
age = myObject.getChildren("person")[0].getAttr("age");
```

Comment: Do you recommend -sending 100 questions, along with their respective multiple choices(images) to the client as a one json response from Server to the client?

Comment: @srigu yes,you can. just use the byte array(base 64 ) image format for sending and receiving images.